# Publishing Facebook Open Graph Stories from Backend

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-access-token

When I try to make a POST to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me/<app_namespace>:<action>` 
with user access_token into body I'm getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 15
  }
}
```

Why Facebook is asking me for **app access_token**? I want to publish a story into wall of user specified by access_token, so I really need to use the application access_code?

Comment: Which exact request are you doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the details of your action configuration in app dashboard. On the bottom, under “Advanced Options”, there is a option “Requires App Token to Publish” – sounds like you have that set to “Yes”.

---

This option exists to prevent users from “cheating” by publishing actions themselves, by using their user access token for your app – for example if you have a game with an Open Graph story about the user reaching a certain level or amount of points, then you probably wouldn’t want users to be able to publish that on their own, without actually achieving the necessary level/points in your app.